# How to animate transition of auto height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, animation

I have div in my template whose content are changing. Which changes height (height auto as contents are dynamic & can be of any height). How Do I animate auto height change using angular animation.

```
    trigger('openClose', [
      state('open', style({
        opacity: 1,
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        opacity: 0,
      })),
      transition('open<=>closed', [style({
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
      }),
      animate('.3s ease')
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('openClose2', [
      state('open', style({
        opacity: 1,
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        opacity: 0,
      })),
      transition('open<=>closed', [style({
        transform: 'translateX(100%)'
      }),
      animate('.3s  ease')
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('openClose3', [
      state('open', style({
        height: '*',
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        height: '*',
      })),
      transition('closed=>open', [
        query('@openClose2', [
          animateChild()
        ]),
        animate('0.3s ease')
      ]),
      transition('open=>closed', [
        query('@openClose', [
          animateChild()
        ]),
        animate('0.3s ease')
      ])
    ]),
```

Tried this but two '*' in height not working